# How to get not matched elements from 2 string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having 2 string arrays. I want to get not matched elements from Both strings.

```cs
string[] stringarray1, stringarray2;
stringarray1 = new string[5]{ "Element 1\n", "Element 2\n", "Element 3\n", "Element 4\n", "Element 5" };
stringarray2 = new string[]{ "Element 2", "Element 3\n", "Element 5" };
```

In the above string array (either in `stringarray1` or `stringarray2`) element may end with `\n` in both. If it's not added to the end of every string element, I need to add, compare and get the not matched elements.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Check out the `Enumerable.Except(...)` extension method in the `System.Linq` library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

```
string[] stringarray1, stringarray2;
                stringarray1 = new string[5] { "Element 1\n", "Element 2\n", "Element 3\n", "Element 4\n", "Element 5" };
                stringarray2 = new string[] { "Element 2", "Element 3\n", "Element 5" };

                // Append '\n' to each elements in both array
                stringarray1 = stringarray1.Select(x => x.Contains("\n") ? x : string.Concat(x, "\n")).ToArray();
                stringarray2 = stringarray2.Select(x => x.Contains("\n") ? x : string.Concat(x, "\n")).ToArray();

                // Non matching elements from both arrays   
                string[] nonMatchingElements = stringarray1.Except(stringarray2).Concat(stringarray2.Except(stringarray1)).ToArray();

    // Output
    "Element 1\n"
    "Element 4\n"
```